# No such file or directory found

Tags: python

I'm having a problem opening .txt file in same directory,
and file do exist there.

```
No such file or directory: 'example.txt'
```

```
f = open("example.txt", "r+") #vscode
```

Both .py and .txt in same folder

Comment: It's not in what Python sees as the current directory.  Print the current directory with `import os; print(os.getcwd()))`.  The current directory isn't necessarily the directory with the Python script in it.

Comment: _in same directory_ That doesn't matter...